# Domain error with square roots

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to copy a code from the book I am learning from. The program is supposed to find the square roots of a quadratic function but once I run the module in IDLE I get an error.

```
#This is a program to find the square roots of a quadratic function.



import math

def main():

    print ("this is a program to find square roots of a quadratic function")
    print()
    a,b,c = eval(input("enter the value of the coefficients respectively"))

    discRoot = math.sqrt( b * b - 4 * a * c )

    root1 = ( - b + discRoot ) / 2 * a 
    root2 = ( - b - discRoot ) / 2 * a

    print ("The square roots of the equation are : ", root1, root2 )
    print()

main()
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/untitled.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/untitled.py", line 13, in main
discRoot = math.sqrt( b * b - 4 * a * c )
ValueError: math domain error
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here ? Is it because the discRoor value is turning out to be negative ?

Comment: What happens when `b * b - 4 * a * c` is negative?

Comment: Please make your question titles more descriptive

Comment: Why use `eval` when you can use `int`?

Comment: @AndrewL. You are correct that this usage of `eval` is bad (like almost every usage is) but `int` won't work here since OP is using `eval` to turn the input `1, 2, 3` to a tuple.

Comment: Ahh, did not see, you're correct @DeepSpace

Comment: @Andrew L.I am still a total beginner and that's why I used eval. I don't know about the int yet.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime `b * b - 4 * a * c` is a negative number, `math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)` will raise a `ValueError`.

Either check that before, or use `sqrt` from the [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/cmath.html) module to allow complex roots:

```
.
.
delta = b * b - 4 * a * c
if delta > 0:
     discRoot = math.sqrt(delta)
else:
    print("No solutions")
.
.
```

Or allow complex roots:

```
import cmath

.
.
discRoot = cmath.sqrt( b * b - 4 * a * c )
.
.
```